# Switching from one thread to another giving segmentation fault

Tags: c, multithreading, assembly, x86-64

I'm trying to develop a user-level thread library in C in x86_64.
I have a function called `machine_switch` which takes the stack pointers of new thread and current thread as the arguments. This function is supposed to switch the threads by backing up the current register values and restoring new ones from the new stack pointer. This is what I have tried.

```
.text
.global machine_switch

machine_switch:
    # address of the new sp is arg1
    # address of the current sp is arg2
    # need to store all required registered for old tcb
    # restore all required registred from the new tcb
    # then when you return, you should get to the new thread 

    pushq %rbx
    pushq %rbp
    pushq %r12
    pushq %r13
    pushq %r14
    pushq %r15

    movq %rdi, %rsp

    popq %r15
    popq %r14
    popq %r13
    popq %r12
    popq %rbp
    popq %rbx

    ret
```

This is the data structure I'm using to store threads.

```
struct tcb { 
  void *sp;  /* Address of stack pointer. 
          * Keep this as first element would ease switch.S 
          * You can do something else as well. 
          */  
  int id;
  int state; /* 1 - ready state
          * 2 - running state
          * 3 - blocked state
          */
};
```

I have a list of `tcb` s. I'm passing `sp` in new and old `tcb` as the arguments for `machine_switch` function.

But this function gives a segmentation fault in when changing the stack pointer. (at `movq %rdi, %rsp`). I checked the arguments of the function, they are correct. Am I missing something?

Comment: How do you get new stack pointer? Maybe you are not using a good value.

Comment: Please make a [mcve].

Comment: @FUZxxl What I wanted to know is what I missed conceptually. Whether there is more to do when switching from one thread to another. The complete code is about 600 lines which is why I didn't post it.

Comment: pushing, changing sp and than popping require some kind of finesse. Are you doing it?

Comment: @pahan Conceptually, your code doesn't look wrong, but I need to see how you invoke it to be sure. It is possible that the bug is not in the code your showed us. Try to boil down your code until you can't remove anything without the bug going away.

Comment: Wait a second, I think I spotted your bug (not sure since I don't know very much about your code): after pushing, the old stack pointer has changed. Where do you store the final old stack pointer? It seems like that you save the wrong value for the old stack pointer.

Comment: The fault is unlikely to be at `movq %rdi, %rsp`, that instruction is just a register copy. You used the debugger wrong, or misunderstood its operation (people frequently mistake gdb errors for program errors).

Comment: @FUZxxl You're right. I'm not updating the old stack pointer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you likely save the old stack pointer before calling `machine_switch`. However, `machine_switch` pushes values on the stack, causing the saved stack pointer to be invalid. To fix this you can pass a pointer to the location where you want to save the old stack pointer and store the pointer after pushing the registers:

```
machine_switch:
    pushq %rbx
    pushq %rbp
    pushq %r12
    pushq %r13
    pushq %r14
    pushq %r15

    movq %rsp,(%rsi) # save old stack pointer
    movq %rdi, %rsp

    popq %r15
    popq %r14
    popq %r13
    popq %r12
    popq %rbp
    popq %rbx

    ret
```